# solaris netstat -rn output clarification

Tags: solaris, routing

We have couple of servers performing the same function.
On some I see following output:

```
Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              10.201.33.1          UG        1         84           
10.201.11.128        10.201.18.33         UG        1         80           
10.201.11.128        10.201.18.1          UG        1          0            (*)
10.201.11.160        10.201.18.1          UG        1         64           
10.201.11.160        10.201.18.33         UG        1          0            (*)
....
```

On other ones:

```
Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              10.202.33.1          UG        1         50           
10.201.11.128        10.202.18.1          UG        1         70           (*)
10.201.11.160        10.202.18.33         UG        1         71           (*)
10.201.16.128        10.202.16.129        UG        1          3           
10.202.11.128        10.202.18.1          UG        1         69           
10.202.11.160        10.202.18.33         UG        1         65           
...
```

Comparing the marked packets `(*)` is there any problem? or everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if there's a problem, but the two routing tables are markedly different.

On the first box, you have static routes to two subnets (`10.201.11.128` and `10.201.11.160`), with two routers configured for each subnet.

On the second, you have static routes to **four** subnets.  The last two lines of its routing table refer to `10.202...` instead of `10.201...`.  Hard to say without knowing more about your config, but it looks like a typo to me.

Edit: In a comment you asked for a description of the `Use` column.  The man page for netstat says:

> The use column displays the number of packets sent using  an
>        combined  routing  and address resolution (A) or a broadcast
>        (B) route.  For a local (L) route this count is  the  number
>        of  packets  received,  and  for  all other routes it is the
>        number of times the routing entry has been used to create  a
>        new combined route and address resolution entry.

Comment: There are more routing info which is not relevant. Please ignore the rest. I'd be glad to have some feedback regarding the Use column where in the first part, there is 0 as a value compared to the second part which contain non-zero value.

Comment: details added to my answer.